# Laravel same controller work with one route and not with another

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.4

#### Update

To avoid all the debug and questions about the ajax call I created a index method in the controller with only a `echo 'hey!'`, and still getting the same stuff:

app.url/blocktest give me a `hey`, but changing to app.url/pictures,  commenting out one route and uncommenting the other give-me a `404` error.

#### Update and

I'm building my first application with laravel (version 5.4) but in the process of make a image upload with crop my route (originally photos) start getting a 404 error, after hours of debugging I get nothing, so changing the route and it started working, then blocked again, so I get a little confused and I think I'm really don't getting something here. my actual routes:

```
  Route::resource('partners', 'PartnersController');
  //Route::resource('pictures', 'PicturesController');
  Route::resource('blocktest', 'PicturesController');
```

this way everything works fine, my ajax post to my PicturesController and everything goes well, here is the controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // echo 'hey';
        $requests = request()->file('picture');
        foreach ($requests as $picture) {
            $filename  = time() . '.' . $picture->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = public_path('pictures/' . $filename);
            Image::make($picture->getRealPath())->crop(600, 600)->save($path);


            $picture = new Picture;
            $picture->partner_id = $request['partner_id'];
            $picture->src = $filename;
            $picture->save();
        }
    }
```

but if I change the routes to:

```
Route::resource('partners', 'PartnersController');
Route::resource('pictures', 'PicturesController');
// Route::resource('blocktest', 'PicturesController')
```

trying to use the `pictures` and point the ajax to the new route I get a 404 from nginx.

Here's the result of a `php artisan route:list`

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                     | Name             | Action                                                    | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                |                  | Closure                                                   | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | partners                | partners.index   | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PartnersController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | partners                | partners.store   | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PartnersController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | partners/create         | partners.create  | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PartnersController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | partners/{partner}      | partners.show    | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PartnersController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | partners/{partner}      | partners.update  | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PartnersController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | partners/{partner}      | partners.destroy | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PartnersController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | partners/{partner}/edit | partners.edit    | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PartnersController@edit    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pictures                | pictures.index   | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PicturesController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | pictures                | pictures.store   | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PicturesController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pictures/create         | pictures.create  | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PicturesController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pictures/{picture}      | pictures.show    | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PicturesController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | pictures/{picture}      | pictures.update  | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PicturesController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | pictures/{picture}      | pictures.destroy | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PicturesController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | pictures/{picture}/edit | pictures.edit    | FrutoProibido\Http\Controllers\PicturesController@edit    | web          |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I think it's a pretty strange behavior, but maybe I'm just not seeing something.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is probably like this:

1) You defined:

```
Route::resource('pictures', 'PicturesController');
```

so you would like to get run for example

```
http://example.com/pictures
```

to get list of pictures

2) But you also created `pictures` directory in `public` directory so when you run

```
 http://example.com/pictures
```

server will try to display content of `pictures` directory in `public` directory

It won't work. You need to use this url either for controller or for files in `public` directory. Otherwise you will get this strange behaviour.

Comment: jesus! Now everything makes sense, so my public directory can't have the same name as my route, it's only this?

Comment: @EduRuiz Yes, if you change name of directory in `public` directory it should work without any problem